About EstimatorQNN forward method: getting different results when explicitly selecting input and weight parameters
I am using qiskit-machine-learning to train a regression NN using EstimatorQNN, as per qiskit-machine-learning we can pass a quantum circuit to EstimatorQNN and the forward pass returns the expectation value of the circuit. My circuit contains 2-Input features so I have 2-qubits and I use 2 trainable weights:
param_x = Parameter("x1")  # Parameter for first qubit in feature map
param_y = Parameter("x2")  # Parameter for second qubit in feature map
param_w1 = Parameter("w1")  # Weight parameter for ansatz
param_w2 = Parameter("w2")  # Weight parameter for ansatz

# Construct a 2-qubit feature map (quantum circuit)
feature_map = QuantumCircuit(2, name="fm")
feature_map.ry(np.pi * param_x, 0)  # Apply ry rotation to qubit 0 with parameter x
feature_map.ry(np.pi * param_y, 1)  # Apply ry rotation to qubit 1 with parameter y

# Construct a 2-qubit ansatz (quantum circuit) with weight parameters
ansatz = QuantumCircuit(2, name="vf")
ansatz.cx(0, 1)  # Apply a CNOT gate between qubits 0 and 1
ansatz.ry(param_w1, 0)  # Apply ry rotation to qubit 0 with weight parameter w1
ansatz.ry(param_w2, 1)  # Apply ry rotation to qubit 1 with weight parameter w2

# Construct the quantum neural network circuit with the feature map and ansatz
qc = QNNCircuit(feature_map=feature_map, ansatz=ansatz)

Now running the following code using one sample of the input features and initial weight will return an expectation value of 0.7097444
regression_estimator_qnn = EstimatorQNN(
    circuit=qc,
)

weights = [0.5, 0.3] #I set this to check the output results
input_data = [0.6493668 , 0.53046681] # One sample of each input in the training dataset

print(regression_estimator_qnn.forward(input_data, weights))

On the other hand if I assign the input parameters and weights as in here:
regression_estimator_qnn = EstimatorQNN(
    circuit=qc,
    input_params=feature_map.parameters,
    weight_params=ansatz.parameters,
)

print(regression_estimator_qnn.forward(input_data, weights))

the result will be 0.16298505
Now running the NN on the first method without explicitly selecting input and weight parameters returns better result, without testing the second method I would have thought that the qnn model I used was actually good but after running the second method I realized something is wrong or at least the first method is actually wrong! I am just confused how or why would that happen since I assume the EstimatorQNN is able to automatically get these parameters from the provided circuit, you can check this from the documentation ! I would really appreciate any help regarding this!
